# Solr schema validation

Tags: solr

I don't understand in Solr wiki, whether Solr takes one `schema.xml`, or can have multiple ones.

I took the schema from Nutch and placed it in Solr, and later tried to run examples from Solr. The message was clear that there was error in schema.

If I have a Solr, am I stuck to a specific schema? If not, where is the information for using multiple ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Solr Wiki - [SchemaXml](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml) page:

> The schema.xml file contains all of the details about which fields
>   your documents can contain, and how those fields should be dealt with
>   when adding documents to the index, or when querying those fields.

Now you can only have one schema.xml file per instance/index within Solr. You can implement multiple instances/indexes within Solr by using the following strategies:

1. [Running Multiple Indexes](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MultipleIndexes) - please see this Solr Wiki page for more details.

   > There are various strategies to take when you want to manage multiple "indexes" in a Single Servlet Container
2. [Running Multiple Cores](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) within a Solr instance. - Again, see the Solr Wiki page for more details...

   > Multiple cores let you have a single Solr instance with separate
   >   configurations and indexes, with their own config and schema for very
   >   different applications, but still have the convenience of unified
   >   administration. Individual indexes are still fairly isolated, but you
   >   can manage them as a single application, create new indexes on the fly
   >   by spinning up new SolrCores, and even make one SolrCore replace
   >   another SolrCore without ever restarting your Servlet Container.

Comment: Thank you this simple distinction was essential for me.